# What's the safest way to escape data when using CSV IMPORT INTO on CockroachDB?

Tags: cockroachdb

I am using BCP with Export with `"` around the strings, and comma is the splitter. Curious, what is the safest way to escape data when using CSV IMPORT INTO?

Answer (score 2):

To escape data when using CSV IMPORT INTO, you should wrap the value being imported in double quotes.

Between the double quotes, the `"` character also acts as an escape sequence if there is another `"` character.

For example, let's say you need to import the string `cat,"dog`

This string would be escaped by with: `"cat,""dog"`. We wrap the string with outer `"` characters, and escape the inner `"` character with another `"` character.